# Cakephp 2.3.10 Non ajax request render ajax layout previously(after) call ajax request

Tags: ajax, cakephp

`CakePHP 2.3.10` `autoRender = false` not stopping rendering ajax layout if go to other non ajax request page after ajax call

I have found one solution not good but ok.
I am pasting the code on every non ajax request method

```
$this->layout = 'default_layout';
```

works fine for me, but I want better solution for this

Answer (score 0):

If you use autoRender = false, not only the layout won't be rendered, but your action will not rendre anything, you'll get a blank page.
 I don't really understant what you want, but try looking at the RequestHandler Component.